# Is there a correlation between schemas and social constructs?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, correlation

While studying Piaget's stages of cognitive development in Educational Psychology, the textbook talks about Piaget using the idea of "schemas" which are mental representations or ideas about what things are and how we deal with them.

I also stumbled upon the theory of social constructionism.  While learning psychology, should I look at these as a correlation or two separate entities?  Also in the field of psychology, does one theory have precedence over another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the two theories are related, but the theories come from two different fields, [cogintive science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_science) and [sociology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociology). First the definitions :

> In psychology and cognitive science, a **[schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_(psychology))** (plural schemata or
>   schemas) describes a pattern of thought or behavior that organizes
>   categories of information and the relationships among them

.

> [**Social constructionism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_constructionism) or the social construction of reality
>   (also social concept) is a theory of knowledge in sociology and
>   communication theory that examines the development of jointly
>   constructed understandings of the world that form the basis for shared
>   assumptions about reality

The social construct is the jointly constructed understanding of many individuals. The understanding of **one** individual is stored as a schema.

Answer (score 1):

Both are from the same field of psychology, To be looked at separately not correlation, I do not believe that one theorie has precedent over the other theorie, they both have value in their own ways.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to how they have value in their own ways?